# if contact number is both empty and does not have 11 digits

Tags: javascript, html

id like my "Invalid contact number" to show if the text field is empty or if it does not contain 11 digits (if the text field has content)

HTML:

```
<label id="number_label">
<b>Contact Number</b>
</label>

<input type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact">
```

Javascript:

```
var contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;

  if (!contact || (contact.val().length >=12 || contact.val().length <=10) ) {
    document.getElementById("number_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Invalid contact number (must contain 11 digits)</span>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("number_label").innerHTML = "Contact Number";
  }
```

My "number_label" id in the if statement should change text and display the error.

Comment: you want a number with exactly 11 digits?

Comment: java is not javascript, there is no reason to tag both languages. and yes, if the number is empty, it can't have 11 digits

Comment: Nit: rewrite `contact.val().length >=12 || contact.val().length <=10)` as `contact.val().length !== 11`

Comment: What part of your code isn't working?

Comment: id like my "Invalid contact number" to show if the text field is empty or if it does not contain 11 digits (if the text field has content)

Comment: That's what you want - what exactly is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: whenever i try to type some numbers that do not add up to 11 characters, the form just loads the "Invalid contact number" and reloads the page going back to the beginning before checking the if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It isn't working

You're calling `.val()` on `contact` (a `String`) which is no good. `.val()` is a *jQuery* method, and is meant to be called on the element itself.

> the form just loads the "Invalid contact number" and reloads the page going back to the beginning

If you're trying to restrict a form from posting, make sure any path in your function that should restrict this has a `return false`.

```js
var label = document.getElementById("number_label");

function validate() {

  var contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;
  if (!contact || contact.length !== 11) {
    label.innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Invalid contact number (must contain 11 digits)</span>";
    return false;
  } else {
    label.innerHTML = "<b>Contact Number</b>";
  }

}
```

```html
<label id="number_label">
    <b>Contact Number</b>
</label>

<input type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact">
<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code has some errors. val() is not a function of the element.

`if (!contact || (contact.**val()**.length >=12 || contact.**val()**.length <=10) ) {`

Follows a fiddle with the code fixed. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jdu1efzx/)